# Propositional Logic: proof involving conditional statements and disjunction conclusion

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Please show me how I should work on the following proof:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/78Ax8.jpg

$${1.~~B\supset{\sim}(A\supset C)\\2.~~{\sim}C\supset{\sim}A\qquad/\therefore D\lor {\sim}B}$$

All I can think of is to assume $B$, and then assume $A\rightarrow C$, and somehow maybe get to $\neg(A\rightarrow C)$. I'm also asked to only use "rules of inference", and cannot use "replacement rules" like De Morgan's law.

I am not sure how to prove the negation of the $A$ and $C$ conditional.

$\qquad{~~1.~~B\supset{\sim}(A\supset C)\\~~2.~~{\sim}C\supset{\sim}A\hspace{10ex}/\therefore D\lor {\sim}B\\~~3.~~\implies~A\hspace{11ex}\text{ACP}\\~~4.~~~~~~\qquad C\hspace{11ex}2,3\text{ MT}\\~~5.~~A\supset C\hspace{13ex}3{-}4\text{ CP}\\~~6.}$

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WhMpA.jpg
Please check this link for the work I've done so far.

Comment: If you want to use De Morgan's law, begin be material implication.

Comment: @hamam_Abdallah I cannot use any equivalence laws, such as De Morgan's. I have edited my question. You can see the new link to find my working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> All I can think of is to assume $B$, and then assume $A\supset C$, and somehow maybe get to ${\sim}(A\supset C)$.

Well, as you have found, you do not need to assume $A\supset C$ when you have derived it.

Also that "somehow maybe get" is "modus ponens" or "conditional elimination", by which $\neg(A\rightarrow C)$ is inferred from having $B$ and $B\supset{\sim}(A\supset C)$ (as assumption and premise).

$\qquad{~~1.~~B\supset{\sim}(A\supset C)\\~~2.~~{\sim}C\supset{\sim}A\hspace{10ex}/\therefore D\lor {\sim}B\\~~3.~~\implies~~A\hspace{11ex}\text{ACP}\\~~4.~~\hspace{7.75ex}C\hspace{11ex}2,3\text{ MT}\quad\textsf{(?)}\\~~5.~~A\supset C\hspace{14ex}3{-}4\text{ CP}\\[1.5ex]~~6.~~\implies~~B\hspace{11ex}\text{ACP}\\~~7.~~\hspace{7.75ex}{\sim}(A\supset C)\hspace{2ex}1,6\text{ MP}\\~~8.\hspace{9ex}A\supset C\hspace{5.75ex}5\text{ Reiteration}\\~~9.}$

So now you have derived a contradiction under the assumption of $B$. ...

Although, if you *can* use *modus tollens*, why not just do that?

> $\qquad{~~1.~~B\supset{\sim}(A\supset C)\\~~2.~~{\sim}C\supset{\sim}A\hspace{10ex}/\therefore D\lor {\sim}B\\~~3.~~\implies~~A\hspace{11ex}\text{ACP}\\~~4.~~\hspace{7.75ex}C\hspace{11ex}2,3\text{ MT}\\~~5.~~A\supset C\hspace{14ex}3{-}4\text{ CP}\\[1.5ex]~~6.~~{\sim}B\hspace{17ex}5,1\text{ MT}}$

Otherwise, if you may not use *modus tolens*, I'd suggest assuming, $B$, $A$, and ${\sim}C$:

${~~1.~~B\supset{\sim}(A\supset C)\\~~2.~~{\sim}C\supset{\sim}A\\\quad{~~3.~~B\\\quad{~~4.~~A\\\quad{~~5.~~{\sim}C\\~~6.~~{\sim}A\\~~7.~~}\\~~8.~~C}\\~~9.~~A\supset C\\10.~~{\sim}(A\supset C)\\11.~~}\\12.~~{\sim} B\\~~~~~~\vdots}$